# Connecting to Amazon Redshift from Azure Data Factory

Tags: amazon-web-services, azure, amazon-redshift, azure-data-factory

We are attempting to connect to an Amazon Redshift Instance from Azure Data Factory as a linked service.

Steps Taken:

- Provisioned Self Hosted Integration Runtime (Azure)
- Created user access to database within Redshift (AWS)
- White list IP addresses of SHIR within security group (AWS)
- Built linked service to Redshift using log in, server address and database name (Azure)

From testing we know that this user log in works with this database for other sources and in general the process has worked for other technologies.

A screenshot of the error message received can be seen [here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BCc33.png)

Any suggestions would be greatly appreciated :)

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

To connect to Amazon Redshift from Azure, look at using the Amazon Redshift **AWS SDK for .NET**. You can use the .NET Service client to write logic that performs CRUD operations on a Redshift cluster.

You can create a service client in .NET with this code:

```
var dataClient = new AmazonRedshiftDataAPIServiceClient(RegionEndpoint.USWest2);
```

Ref docs here:

https://docs.aws.amazon.com/sdkfornet/v3/apidocs/items/RedshiftDataAPIService/TRedshiftDataAPIServiceClient.html

Comment: Thanks, can you do the same using a python version of the SDK?

Comment: Yes -- Python does support Redshift as well